# How can i pass properties to WPF style with DependencyProperty?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, dynamic, dependency-properties

Im trying to create a reusable style for a button with WPF, and i want to pass parameters from .xaml but it's not working  even when i insert a breakpoint in the ButtonStyle Class while debugging he don't enter in it, i miss something and i didn't find it.

Thank you.

ButtonStyle Class :

```
Public Class ButtonStyle
Inherits System.Windows.Controls.Button

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly BackgroundColorProperty As DependencyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", GetType(Brush), 
GetType(ButtonStyle))

Public Property BackgroundColor As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(value As Brush)
        SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly BackgroundColorHoverProperty As DependencyProperty 
= DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColorHover", GetType(Brush), 
GetType(ButtonStyle))

Public Property BackgroundColorHover As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(BackgroundColorHoverProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(value As Brush)
        SetValue(BackgroundColorHoverProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly BorderColorProperty As DependencyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("BorderColor", GetType(Brush), 
GetType(ButtonStyle))

Public Property BorderColor As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(BorderColorProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(value As Brush)
        SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly BorderColorHoverProperty As DependencyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("BorderColorHover", GetType(Brush), 
GetType(ButtonStyle))

Public Property BorderColorHover As Brush
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(BorderColorHoverProperty), Brush)
    End Get
    Set(value As Brush)
        SetValue(BorderColorHoverProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly IconeProperty As DependencyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Icone", GetType(ImageSource), 
GetType(ButtonStyle))

Public Property Icone As ImageSource
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(IconeProperty), ImageSource)
    End Get
    Set(value As ImageSource)
        SetValue(IconeProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DictionaryResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <local:ButtonStyle Width="150" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource 
StyleBoutonHello}"   Icone="img.png" BorderColor="red" 
BackgroundColor="red" BackgroundColorHover="Blue" BorderColorHover="blue" 
Content="Hello"></local:ButtonStyle>
</Grid>
```

DictionnaryResource.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

<Style x:Name="StyleBoutonHello" x:Key="StyleBoutonHello" TargetType=" 
{x:Type local:ButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="{Binding BorderColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"  Value="red" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hello" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Image Name="Img" Width="30" Height="30" Source="{Binding 
Icone, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="Img"  
Value="{Binding Icone, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding 
BackgroundColorHover}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>  
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Although you call it ButtonStyle, it is not a *reusable style for a button*, but just a custom Button control, i.e. a class derived from Button. The naming is rather confusing and needs to be changed.

Comment: Also, exposing BackgroundColor and BorderColor properties of type Brush is nonsense (and badly named) when Button already has Background and BorderBrush.

Comment: Besides all that, the ControlTemplate of your custom Button simply ignores all these properties. Take a look at the [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.controltemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see how it has to be done. There have to be elements with properties bound like e.g. `{TemplateBinding Background}`. Also worth reading: [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Answer (score 0):

For Example:-

1) Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

```
Class MainWindow
 Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

 Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
 Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
 End Sub

 Public Shared ReadOnly MyProperty1 As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserName", GetType(String), GetType(MainWindow), New UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty))

 Public Property UserName() As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(MyProperty1), String)
    End Get
    Set
        SetValue(MyProperty1, Value)
        OnPropertyChanged("Name")
    End Set
 End Property  
End Class
```

2) Now bind the value in XAML

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Now whenever you change UserName it will reflect to UI!!!.